# The name 'DisplayPromptAsync' does not exist in the current context - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to implement a simple Dialog with a text input in Android Xamarin, using a *DisplayPromptAsync*:

```
    private async void ShowDialogAsync() {
        string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 1", "What's your name?");
    }
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups

But I'm getting the next error:

```
CS0103 The name 'DisplayPromptAsync' does not exist in the current context
```

And it doesn't give me the option to import any library. My version of Xamarin Forms is **4.6.0.726**

It's something I'm missing...?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In what context are you trying to access `DisplayPromptAsync` as it is a member of `Page`

Comment: I'm trying to access it inside a ViewModel...

Comment: `DisplayPromptAsync` is a **page** method.  You can't do it from a VM unless you have a reference to the page.  A common workaround is to use `App.Current.MainPage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ViewModel, just add the *App.Current.MainPage* before the call of *DisplayPromptAsync*:

```
private async void ShowDialogAsync() {

    string result = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Question 1", "What's your name?");
    
    // OK
    if (result != null)
    {
         // do something here
    } else {
         // do something else here
    } 
}
```

Thanks to Jason for his reply...

Answer (score 1):

**Update NuGet for Xamarin.Forms**
I have updated NuGet for Xamarin.Forms from 4.2.X to 4.3.X in all projects and now it works. Apparently in 4.2.X the method "appears" available with intellisense, but at runtime it fails with the mentioned error. Updating all NuGet packages seemed to solve the problem.